# subquery with distinct clause in query builder/laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

```
SELECT * FROM `movie_list`
WHERE `movie_id` IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT movie_id FROM `movie_genre` where genre_id in (12,18,53)) 
AND rated IN 
('Not Rated','N/A')
```

How can i convert the above to a query builder syntax:

```
$movies = DB::table('movie_list')
                  ->whereIn('movie_id',function($query){
                      $query->select.....

                  })->get();
```

I have the inner one: it goes like this:

```
DB::table('movie_genre')
                     ->whereIn('genre_id', array(12,18,53))
                     ->distinct()
                     ->get(array('movie_id'));
```

How do i use this result with the rest of my query?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this alot smoother with Eloquent Models, but assuming you don't have your models setup, this should do the trick (untested)

```
$ids = DB::table('movie_genre')
        ->whereIn('genre_id', [12,18,33])
        ->distinct()
        ->get(['movie_id'])
        ->toArray();


$movies = DB::table('movie_list')
        ->whereIn('movie_id', array_values($ids))
        ->get();
```

Comment: DB::table('movie_list')->whereIn('movie_id',function($query){
   $query->select(DB::raw('movie_id'))
                      ->from('movie_genre')
                      ->whereIn('genre_id',array(12,18,53))
       ->distinct();
  })->paginate(5);